# Open MPI Virtual Timer Expired

Tags: linux, mpi

I'm using Open MPI 1.8 on Gentoo 3.13 to manage the data transfer from one program to another via a server/client concept. Both the server and the clients are launched via `mpiexec` as separate processes. After some days (this is quite a heavy computation...), I sometimes receive the error

```
mpiexec noticed that process rank 0 with PID 17213 on node XXX exited on signal 26 (Virtual timer expired).
```

Unfortunately, the error is not reproducible in a reliable way, i.e., the error does not appear always and not always at the same point in the program flow. I also experienced this error on other machines. I already tracked the issue down to the `ITIMER_VIRTUAL` which, upon expiration, delivers `SIGVTALRM` (see, e.g., http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setitimer.2.html). In the BUGS section of the man page, it says that

> Under very heavy loading, an ITIMER_REAL timer may expire before the signal from a previous expiration has been delivered. The second signal in such an event will be lost.

I wonder if something similar might also hold for `ITIMER_VIRTUAL`? Did anyone experience similar problems and can confirm the error?

The only workaround I can think of is to invoke `setitimer(...)` and try to manipulate the timer myself. However, I hope there is another way since I can't always modify the clients' source code. Any suggestions?

Comment: There is not a single occurrence in the Open MPI 1.8 source code of any of `setitimer`, `SIGVTALRM` or `ITIMER_VIRTUAL`. I would rather look at your program or a 3rd party library it possibly uses as the cause of the problem.

Comment: Yes, I already checked the Open MPI source code for an occurrence of  `setitimer`, `SIGVTALRM` or `ITIMER_VIRTUAL` before posting my question and I know there are none. I thought this could be more related to the Linux kernel than to Open MPI directly. Since I tested different setups without always the same third party libraries involved, I'm really not sure if this problem is related to a library in my code...

Comment: What language is your program written into? It appears that both Haskell and Ruby use virtual timers to implement user-level threads and under heavy load unexpected signals start popping.

Comment: It's implemented in C/C++.

Comment: I have to apologize. Digging a bit deeper revealed that there was indeed a third-party library which was used in all our test setups and was causing the timer to expire. @HristoIliev Could you please change your comment to an answer, so I can accept and close this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this question has not been answered officially, I will do it on behalf of Hristo (@HristoIliev: I hope this is ok for you). As was pointed out in the first comment to my question, there is not a single hint in the Open MPI source code which can have caused the virtual timer expiration. Indeed, the timer problem was related to a third-party library which made the code crash after an unpredictable time (depending on the current loading of the machine).